# Improvement of s21 and s11 parameters of my CMOS Differential LNA

Tags: rf

I have tried to simulate a Differential LNA in LTspice and have run into problems regarding s11 and s21 parameters. I have attached the schematic and the graphs below. I have primarily 2 doubts:

1. I designed the LNA to operate at 2.4GHz, so why is s11's minima at a different frequency.The common solution on the internet is to change the width of the MOSFET's but that comes at the loss of optimum width calculated for the LNA. Is there any other way?
2. How do I improve my gain?

[image: LTspice ckt][image: s11 parameter graph][image: s21 parameter graph]

Apologies if the questions(or the ckt) doesn't make sense.This is my first time dealing with  RF and am still getting a hang of it

Comment: Double check the values of gate inductors L2/L6: 840 femtahenry of your circuit is suspiciously low a value; the shortest PCB traces have much higher inductances (~10 nH per inch) (1nH = 1,0000,000 fH)

Comment: @V.V.T Thanks for that! I had mistakenly interchanged my Lgate and Lsource inductor values. And this has improved my s21 parameter. However my s11 parameter now shows a peak instead of a trough and the resonant frequency has shifted to around 1.5GHz.Any suggestions on that?